# Adding and Animating DIVs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to create div boxes step by step and animate them for several times when a button is pressed. I created a running sample code, and everything is going well. It goes right to the endhost, then it goes left again to its original place.

I want to simulate TCP, exactly as shown at http://histrory.visualland.net/tcp_fast_recovery.html.
Now I want each step when the button is pressed, and that between the DIVs in the same step, there should be delay when they move so one can distinguish them once they are animated. Can anyone help me with that?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var d = $("#t");
    var number = $("#number1").val();
    var speed = 2000;

    //  if(state==true){
    d.animate({
      left: '+=230px'
    }, speed);
    
    d.animate({
      left: '+=230px'
    }, speed);
    
    d.animate({
      top: '+=20px',
      backgroundColor: "#f09090",
      text: '12'
    }, speed / 4, "swing", function() {
      $('#span').fadeOut(500, function() {
        $(this).text('a1').fadeIn(500);
      });
    });
    
    d.delay(1000).animate({
      left: '-=230px'
    }, speed);
    
    d.animate({
      left: '-=230px'
    }, speed);
    d.fadeOut();
  });
});
```

```html
<body id="myapp">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" style="left: 0px; width: 50px; height: 50px;" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; left: 275px; position: fixed; " />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; right: 0px; position: fixed;  left: 548px;" />
  <div style="border: 1px dashed gray; position: absolute; left: 55px; height: 20px; width: 500px; opacity: 0.5; top: 10px; z-index=-1;"></div>
  <div style="border: 1px dashed gray; position: absolute; left: 55px; height: 20px; width: 500px; opacity: 0.5; top: 30px; z-index=-1;"></div>

  <p>
    Speed (mS): <input value="1000" id="number1" type="number" style="position: relative"></input>
    <button style="position: absolute; top: 150px">Apply!</button>
    <!-- dynamic area -->
    <div id="t" style="position: absolute; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width: 20px; height: 20px; left: 60px; top: 10px; background-color: lightgreen">
      <font id="span">
        1
      </font>
    </div>
  </p>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: So to clarify: you want multiple little green boxes to come one and start animating. One box each time the user clicks the 'apply!' button. Right?

Comment: @DamienBlack Yes, but for the first click, the first DIV, the second click for the next 2 DIVs, then click again, so the next 4 DIVs should go

Comment: @oGeez Your link is just showing a text!! Speed is not important at this moment. Let's focus on the DIV creation first, something like http://histrory.visualland.net/tcp_fast_recovery.html